# Sonar - Custom Time Changes or Time Span

Tags: sonarqube

In many reports there is the option to limit the report to a time span.  I believe they call it a differential xxx (e.g. filter, dashboard, etc...).  In the drop down there are three options: all time, 30 days, or 90 days.  Is this customizable?  Could it show the last 7 or 14 days?  Could is show custom time spans.  I would like to be to report on a sprint (we are practicing Agile Scrum).  The behavior of developers is rhythmic and it would make the most sense to show reports for a sprint as this is the time span that determines the rhythm.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the answers to all your questions at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views#DifferentialViews-DifferentialViewsSettings

Comment: Updated URL: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views#DifferentialViews-DifferentialViewsSettings

Comment: The URLs are dead, both